# Is going to graduate school the same place I went to undergrad okay?

Tags: graduate-school

Is it okay to get my bachelor's and master's degrees at the same school?  I intend to go into industry in computer science.

OK = will not substantially harm future prospects.

Getting a doctoral degree is not planned.

Edit: I might need to take out loans to go to a different school.

Comment: "ok" for what purpose?

Comment: Also see [Which is preferable, to go to graduate school at same school as undergrad or to go to a lower-ranked school?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/28385/which-is-preferable-to-go-to-graduate-school-at-same-school-as-undergrad-or-to)

Comment: What future prospects are you referring to? Employment? What kind of job? (If you're asking about how non-academic, non-research employers perceive a masters+bachelors from the same university, it might be on topic at [workplace.se] but off topic here per the [help/on-topic].)

Comment: This is probably off-topic then (I have no interest in an academic career)

Comment: Yeah, then probably a bunch of academics are not the right people to answer this question :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it could better be answered on workplace.SE.

Comment: I did exactly this (except my BA was in math and MS was in CS, so I avoided Bob Brown's excellent point about repeating professors). Have yet to see a negative reaction from any potential employer.

Comment: For industry, you should go to what is considered the strongest school within your reach. Reputation of your school, and - maybe - your adviser there if known in their field, as well as your GPA, and possibly your class selection, are all that matters. No one gives a rodent's behind if you went to the same, or a different school.

Answer (score 5):

Hiring managers in industry will care more about the reputation of your master's degree than about where you earned your bachelor's degree.

If your undergraduate degree is from a medium-to-small school, you will probably have the same professors if you take your master's there.  In other words, you will have learned much of what they have to teach you when you finish your undergraduate degree.  So, for maximum learning, consider a master's from a different school that has a good reputation in industry.

Comment: "In other words, you will have learned most of what they have to teach you when you finish your undergraduate degree": I hope you're kidding, or you had not very knowledgeable professors.

Comment: Not kidding.  My experience is that undergrad education is about breadth and grad school is about depth.  Different professors will give the student a different view in grad school.

Comment: A single professor can give breadth to an audience and depth to another: it's not that teaching to one group makes you unable to teach to the other.

Comment: Anyway, I concur that changing school is frequently a good thing for various reasons, but not for the one you highlighted.

Comment: I've edited my answer to change "most" to "much."